# How do I print just the final output of the index in a for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, spyder

I want to print just the last line that I get from my for the for statement. For example a random string is generated and it prints as so.
e
ej
ejb
ejbG
ejbGl

I want it to just print out ejbGl. If I take the print(easy_input) out of the loop it will print ejbGl, but I need that to stay in the loop so that I can used it for the if statements and for the user to see the word they have to type. I am not allowed to share the cse231_random, so this might make this difficult to find a solution.

```
import string
import random
import time
from cse231_random import randint
ALPHABET_EASY = string.ascii_letters 
ALPHABET = string.ascii_letters + string.punctuation



 easy_str = ""
length=random.randint(3, 5)
for i in range(length):
    index=randint(0, len(ALPHABET_EASY))
    easy_str += ALPHABET_EASY[index]
    print(easy_str)
    start= time.time()
    easy_input=input("\nEnter this string:")
    stop= time.time()
    easy_input=easy_input.replace(" ", "")
    easy_input=easy_input
    if stop-start>10:
        print("Oops! Too much time.")
        continue
    elif easy_input.lower()==easy_str.lower():
        print("Good job! You spent {} of 10 seconds entering string [{}][{}]".format(stop-   start,easy_str,easy_input))
        continue
    elif easy_input.lower()!=easy_str.lower():
        print("Incorrect.")
        continue
```

Comment: Why don‘t you use two loops, one for building the string and one for the user query? Why don’t you print easy_str after the loop?

Comment: I see what you mean but if I did that I wouldnt be able to loop back and get a random string again. I forgot to mention it put I want it to play 10 times before it stops. If I print easy_str after the loop, the user wont know what to type

Comment: What do you mean by „loop back and get a random string again“? easy_str is built iteratively, it is never reset. You could built the *entire* string first (loop 1), print it, then challenge the user for the first 1, 2, 3, ... characters (loop 2).